# How to ignore parametr in query without chaging query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I have a query copied from dataset of SSRS report, with for example 3 parameters. In real situation I have many about 30 parameters. I want to test this query in SSMS and handle parameters with my own values. But I want fill to query one parameter - @par1, other must take have all values.

```
drop table testtable;
create table testtable(param1 int,param2 int,param3 int)
insert into testtable values 
(1,10,20),(2,11,21),(3,12,22);

--added parametrs to help query work
declare @par1 int;
declare @par2 int;
declare @par3 int;
set @par1=1;
set @par2= ? --what i need to put here to have only @par1 condition implemented in query
set @par3= ? --what i need to put here to have only @par1 condition implemented in query

-- Dataset Copyed from SSRS Report. And I dont want to delete anything from here, because query is complex in real situation.
select *
from testtable
where 
param1=@par1 and param2=@par2 and param3=@par3
```

Comment: Do you want to ignore the parameters when it is `NULL`

Comment: if parameter is null. I don't want to ignore it. In this case will be Where @par = null

Comment: I don't think you can do what you're looking for. I think the best option would be to amend the query. Also if you could do this, and you don't have a good understanding of the query, you could likely introduce a bug.

Comment: It is not comfortably every time change big query to test it. I want to find more simple solution.

Comment: You have to set the default values while declaring the parameters.

Comment: Can you describe in detail what do you mean ?

Comment: You can use dynamic SQL and have only those columns in the WHERE-Clause you really need. Maybe this blog post helps you: http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/high-performance-procedures/

Comment: So if @par3 = Null your where clause must be something like `... and param3 is Null`. Correct?

Answer (score 3):

I guess this will work for you

```
select *
from testtable
where (param1=@par1 or @par1 is null) 
  and (param2=@par2 or @par2 is null) 
  and (param3=@par3 or @par3 is null)
```

Comment: You modificate the query, but I Don't want to do it. Because In real situation parameters are located not only in where condition. They exists in joins, select fields,etc.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there is no way to do what you want...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want ignore the parameters if they are `Null` try this:

```
select * from testtable
where 
( ( param1 = @par1 ) or ( param1 is null) )
and ( ( param2 = @par2 ) or ( param2 is null) )
and ( ( param3 = @par3 ) or ( param3 is null) )
```

**Update**

Just saw that you don't want to change the query. So that is not a solution. I can't come up with something.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select *
from testtable
where  ISNULL(@par1,0) IN (param1,0)
  and ISNULL(@par2,0) IN (param2,0)
  and ISNULL(@par3,0) IN (param3,0)
```